# Postgres: ODBC: ERROR: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly; Error while executing the query

Tags: postgresql, odbc, ssl

I'm currently in Australia and so is the database.

Staff attempting to connect to the database from overseas (USA, UK) consistently run into the error: `ERROR: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly; Error while executing the query`, when they try to connect.  People here can connect fine without that error but anyone overseas will receive that error if their query lasts longer than say 1 minute?

The database is a postgres RDS hosted in AWS Sydney region.

What is the cause of an SSL connection closing like this? Is it the server or is it just caused by the latency of someone overseas trying to connect to the database?  Is there any way to combat this?

This error was from an ODBC connection using Power BI or Tableau
We find a similar error when querying from Python or DBeaver as well.

Comment: There probably is a malicious firewall involved.

Comment: You mean on the database side or the client side?

Comment: Could be either, or somewhere in between.